# Trading between different cryptocoins

Tags: exchanges, alternatives, currencies, trading

Is there a website that allows one to trade multiple different cryptocoins (Bitcoins, Namecoins, SolidCoins, RuCoins, LiteCoins, etc) all in one place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[BTC-E](https://btc-e.com) currently offers trading pairs of BTC/USD, BTC/RUB, SC/BTC, SC/USD, GG/BTC, TBX/BTC, FBX/BTC, LTC/BTC, LTC/USD, RUC/BTC, RUC/USD, RUC/RUB, NMC/BTC and RUB/USD

Answer (score 4):

[Vircurex.com](https://vircurex.com)
now offers traiding support for many of the crypto currencies: BTC, NMC, LTC, LQC, I0C, IXC, DVC, GG and SC. You can trade between any pair of these at will. USD and EUR are also supported to buy or sell all these crypto-currencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty comprehensive list over at [TradeLi.st](http://tradeli.st)

BTC-e:

```
Fiat

 BTC/USD  BTC/RUR  BTC/EUR  LTC/USD  LTC/RUR  LTC/EUR  NMC/USD  NVC/USD  USD/RUR  EUR/USD

Crypto

 LTC/BTC  NMC/BTC  NVC/BTC  TRC/BTC  PPC/BTC  FTC/BTC  XPM/BTC
```

Coinex, Virtuex, Cryptsy (too many to list)